# Add a image on a cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image, asp.net-mvc-4

I've an WebSite written in Asp.Net.
I wish to add a image on the login page (a cshtml file).

I tried this :

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/logo.png")" alt="Answer logo" />
```

But it doesn't works, the image is not displayed.

Is there specific settings to add on the "Content" folder or on the "logo.png" file ?

My project structure :

```
Project
 |
 |- Content
     |- logo.png
 |- View
     |- Auth
         |- LogIn.cshtml
```

Comment: What about src="../Content/logo.png"

Comment: Describe "doesn't work". Does the rendered HTML look correct? Does the page try to request the image from the server? What is the HTTP Status Code of the response? What happens if you navigate directly to the URL where the image is hosted?

Comment: @BasantaMatia That should not be necessary, as `~/` is an application root relative URL, which is almost always preferable to a relative URL.

Comment: Your code should work as long the image exist. What is happening now ? Are you gettting a 404 error ? to which url ?

Comment: @mason : "Doen't work" = The alternate text is displayed instead of the picture. Under chrome, when I right-clicked "Open image in a new tab", "the resource cannot be found". Perhaps I've missing to correctly setted properties on my picture or on the Content folder ?

Comment: Okay, so that means when you check your network tools, you see a 404 status code when you try to navigate directly to the page? Keep in mind that your issue has nothing to do with your Razor file, that might as well be eliminated from your question. Your trouble is simply with getting an image to be served to the browser.

Comment: Have you logged into the web server and verified that the logo.png file is in the Content folder, and that the Content folder is in the root of your website?

Comment: Yes, "Content" is into the WebSite root and "logo.png" exists into Content directory

Comment: In that case I would double check that the account your site is running as has permissions to the file and is configured to serve PNG files. How you do this depends on your hosting provider. Just as a test, you might also move the file to the root of your website and then access it directly there and see if it gets served correctly.

Comment: can you inspect in browser inspector ?

Comment: @mason : If I copied file to root folder, the image is also not accessible. I checked permission, but there are OK. My WebSite is running under IIS, I added this handler in my web.config but without success : `<handlers> <add name="Picture" path="*.png" verb="GET"   type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" /> </handlers>`

Comment: You shouldn't need to add a specific handler....what hosting service are you using? Do they have a screen in their admin panel where you can configure what file types to serve? Have you tried asking their support team?